# Smooth morphisms vs. submersions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

This question is ***almost*** a duplicate of [that question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/375368/4149),
which has a [good answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/375415/4149).
The difference is that I ask for  ***references*** rather than proofs.
By a reference I mean a reference to a book, or to a paper, or to an arXiv preprint.
The answerer does not know references; see
[his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375368/smooth-morphism-algebraic-geometry-vs-submersion-differential-geo-ehresma/375415#comment997469_375415).

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a surjective morphism of algebraic varieties over $\Bbb C$.
Consider the following assertions:

> **Assertion 1.** If the morphism $f$ is smooth, then it is a *submersion*,
> that is, for any $\Bbb C$-point $x\in X({\Bbb C})$,
> the linear map of the tangent spaces $d_x\colon T_x(X)\to T_{f(x)} Y$ is surjective.

> **Assertion 2.** If the varieties $X$ and $Y$ are smooth,
> then the morphism $f$ is smooth if and only if it is a submersion.

I am asking for *references* for these two assertions.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Assertion 2 is Proposition 10.4 (ch. III) in Hartshorne. Assertion 1 follows from EGA IV, Proposition 17.2.3 (taking $Z=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}) $).

Comment: Many thanks indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assertion 2 is stated as Proposition 10.4 page 270 in Hartshorne's book. In fact, assertions 1 is equally proved in Hartshorne proposition 10.4 (though it is not in the statement of the proposition). It suffices to notice that the kernel of:
$$ \Omega_{Y/\mathbb{C}} \longrightarrow \Omega_{X/ \mathbb{C}} \longrightarrow \Omega_{X/Y} \longrightarrow 0$$
is a torsion-sheaf as:

$\bullet$ $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank $\dim X - \dim Y$ (definition of smoothness)

$\bullet$ $\Omega_{X/\mathbb{C}}$ (resp. $\Omega_{Y/\mathbb{C}}$) is generically of rank $\dim X$ (resp. $\dim Y$) because $X$ is integral (resp. $Y$ is integral).

Then dualize this exact sequence an oberve that dual of a torsion sheaf is zero.